# Movie: huge Transformers-like robot with red eyes attacks a mafia fighting two Asian actors

Tags: story-identification, movie

My girlfriend says she saw a robot movie long time ago, and even I seem to remember that I also saw that movie sometime in my life, but can't remember exactly what movie/TV show it is. This is what she remembers, that also got me thinking.

- It was a 2000-2010 movie (She thinks)
- There was a HUGE (Transformers-like) robot with red eyes (of course)
- also there were two younger Asian actors, one allegedly had red hair (she says 
  maybe they made that robot by themselves? Not sure about this)
- two of them got in a fight/war with gang/mafia, and robot attacked all of them in some kind of a mall?
- they had to shut it down after catching it, later they tied him up and dragged him on the streets
- in some point of the movie they were agreeing on/near water
- they threw him into the ocean (not sure about this part though)

I searched and looked everywhere, and it doesn't seem like *Transformers, Pacific Rim, Atlantic Rim, Terminator* (red eyes), *Robot Jox* (too old and no gang?) and so on, so I think it's not some kind of AAA movie, maybe I am mistaken but still couldn't find it.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: So, just to clarify, are you using "mafia" as shorthand for "organized crime" or do you remember them being Italian? And were the two protagonists fighting the gang when the robot showed up and attacked both sides? Were the gang a major part of the narrative or just that scene?

Comment: Organized crime as in gang/mob, my native language is not English, so that may be the reason I wrote it that way, thanks for trying though! EDIT: (Don't know if they were Italian)